# `E575: viminfo: Illegal starting char in line: ...` on startup

Tags: startup, error

Recently on starting vim I've been getting an error message like this:

```
E575: viminfo: Illegal starting char in line: wait_until(lambda
_:<80><fc>^B ^[ldWA)^[:w^Mkkkdd^[:w^M<80><fd>c<80><fd>b248Gwwi_zzz^[:w^M<80><fd>c<80><fd>bkkkkj/refresh^M^c^[ma/browser.rfer<80>kb<80>kb<80>kbresh^[/refresh^MnN^ceb<80>kbdrie<80>kbver^[:w^M<80><fd>c<80><fd>b<80><fd>c<80><fd>b<80><fd>c<80><fd>b<80><fd>c<80><fd>b<80><fd>,<80><fd>-<80><fd>.^[^[^[^[<80><fd>W<80><fd>,<80><fd>.<80><fd>c<80><fd>b<80><fd>c<80><fd>b<80><fd>c<80><fd>bjodisplay_remaining_hours=<80>kb = trello9"<80>kb<80>kb("^V^V")^[^wwwwdt/..:w^M/zzz^Mkkjo@display_remaining_staff_hours^[ma/ldispla<80>kb<80>kb^[<80>kb^[ggjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjlkkkllllllllllllllllis<80>kb_staff^[*A.acceptance_test("At<80>kbT1")^[:w^Mjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhdt(^[:w^M<80><fd>L<80><fd>L<80><fd>L<80><fd>L<80><fd>,<80><fd>.<80><fd>L<80><fd>L<80><fd>c<80><fd>b<80><fd>c<80><fd>b<80><fd>c<80>
```

It doesn't happen when I launch with `vim -u NONE` but it does happen if I clear out my entire `~/.vimrc` and move my `~/.vim` directory. It looks like there's an error in a tags file somewhere but I can't find with one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out the answer was in the error message all along.. the offending file was `~/.viminfo` which was somehow corrupted.

Comment: well, it does say the error is in the `viminfo`...

Comment: It does, but it says `viminfo`, not `.viminfo` or `~/.viminfo`, so as someone who didn't even know that that file existed, it looked more like a generic tag than a filename.

Comment: And on windows it tends to be: "C:\Users\<username>\_viminfo"

Answer (score 3):

For me, this problem keeps showing up even if I delete the `~/.viminfo` file - not right away, but a couple of days later.

I just noticed there's a way to skip using the viminfo file entirely, as detailed here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332707/22734

In summary, put the following in your `~/.vimrc`

```
let skip_defaults_vim=1
set viminfo=""
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve this:

1. rm ~/.viminfo
2. vim ~/.viminfo # new file, leave it blank, then just wq.
3. source terminal et voila

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Could you clarify "source terminal"? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Also note that not all users are on \*nix, so `rm` may not be the right term: perhaps you meant "Remove"? (similar with `~` in paths, etc.) I assume you mean `:wq`? If you structure the bullets in full sentences, you won't need to `#` comment out parts, and the whole answer would be more readable.

Comment: In addition to what Ben said (which I agree 100% with) note that your second step should be `touch ~/.viminfo` which is much more efficient than opening vim just to create a file. (Or even replace steps 1 and 2 by `echo '' > ~/.viminfo`)

Answer (score 1):

Noticed this error when I had forgot to start the line with `:` in `.viminfo` file for example `set tabstop=4`. To get rid of this error had to add `:` at the beginning of the line as below.

```
:set tabstop=4
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was caused because I'd done a search-and-replace to replace a string which had been encoded in utf-8 but opened by Vim as encoding=latin1 .  The string was saved in C:\Users\me_viminfo under "Command Line History" in these lines:

```
?
Ã¢Â€/if
|2,1,1681779433,10,"Ã¢Â€/if"
```

Deleting those lines from _viminfo stopped the error messages.
But if I do a search-and-replace like that again, it will reappear.

Comment: Same for me. I went for tabula rasa, removed my .viminfo file entirely, and the error went away. But I'm afraid it will re-surface when I do a similar edit in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think it occurred after I deleted a repo from my computer.

I first noticed it when trying to do a git merge from terminal, so I originally assumed it was an issue with git.

As describe above it is an issue with the `~/.viminfo` file.

I resolved it by opening the `~/.viminfo` in a text editor and removing the leading `"`.

Now everything seems to work fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `~/.viminfo` only helped me to solve the problem temporarily. Later the error poped up again.

I finally resolved the problem by adding a `>` in the `~/.viminfo` file.

I opened `~/.viminfo` using vim and there was one line in red that showed up to me, so I just fixed that line through adding a `>`. You should add or delete something in your `~/.viminfo` by comparing the wrong line in `~/.viminfo` and other right lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows, and resolved this by removing the `_viminfo` file at user home directory (i.e. `c:\Users\<username>\_viminfo`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. rm ~/.viminfo
2. touch ~/.viminfo

This solves my problem.

Comment: This is already covered in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a viminfo save in default ansi encoding result illegal char, I have add `c` in viminfo parameters saved the question.

```
set viminfo=%,<100,'10,/50,:100,h,f0,c,n~/.vim/viminfo
```

See: https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27viminfo%27